# Idle impersonation for more than 2 minutes is invalidating token

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf

I have an application that does lots of local processing after starting user impersonation. But after I complete my local processing the application invalidates the user impersonation token, if the time taken for local processing exceeds 2 minutes, and fails to access any privileged network resources. The error message recorded shows invalid token.

Is there any OS level setting where I can keep define the time before impersonation tokens are invalidated automatically?

Thank You for any helpful inputs.

Comment: Can you post the code. let us see how you are calling impersonation ?

Comment: I was grouping similar tasks under the impersonation calls. The problem seems to be gone when I split my tasks under impersonation context. Lesson is avoid lengthy (time consuming) tasks under impersonation context, instead split the tasks into as many small calls as possible.